# Flutter, how to treat a container as a panel or something similar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is there a possibility to change panels as well as java? check this video https://youtu.be/cpGw6rnQNxg , I want to be able to do that kind of transition in flutter, I mean I want to treat this main container as a panel, and then when the user tap in any of the button that I have in that screen I want to be  able to change the panel, but just that panel and not all the screen.

This is the actual code and you can compile it without problem, no dependencies nedded

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Prueba2 extends StatefulWidget {
  Prueba2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PruebaState createState() => _PruebaState();
}

class _PruebaState extends State<Prueba2> {
  List<bool> isSelected;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isSelected = [true, false];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 10),
            child: isSelected[0]
                ? Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) - 20,
                    height: 240,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ToggleButtons(
                          borderColor: Colors.black,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey,
                          borderWidth: 2,
                          selectedBorderColor: Colors.black,
                          selectedColor: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 225,
                              child:
                                  Container(child: Center(child: Text('Ida'))),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 225,
                              child: Container(
                                  child: Center(child: Text('Ida y Vuelta'))),
                            ),
                          ],
                          isSelected: isSelected,
                          onPressed: (index) {
                            setState(() {
                              for (var i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
                                if (i == index) {
                                  isSelected[i] = true;
                                } else {
                                  isSelected[i] = false;
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 220,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('Origen'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.airline_seat_recline_extra),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 220,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('Destino'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.airline_seat_recline_extra),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 330,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('Fecha de partida'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 20,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('+ 1 -'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.directions_run),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 450,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            child: Text('Buscar',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) - 20,
                    height: 240,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ToggleButtons(
                          borderColor: Colors.black,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey,
                          borderWidth: 2,
                          selectedBorderColor: Colors.black,
                          selectedColor: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 225,
                              child:
                                  Container(child: Center(child: Text('Ida'))),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 225,
                              child: Container(
                                  child: Center(child: Text('Ida y Vuelta'))),
                            ),
                          ],
                          isSelected: isSelected,
                          onPressed: (index) {
                            setState(() {
                              for (var i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
                                if (i == index) {
                                  isSelected[i] = true;
                                } else {
                                  isSelected[i] = false;
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 220,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('Origen'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.airline_seat_recline_extra),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 220,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('Destino'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.airline_seat_recline_normal),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 330 / 2,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('Fecha de ida'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 330 / 2,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('Fecha de vuelta'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 50,
                              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey[200],
                                label: Text('+ 1 -'),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.directions_run),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 450,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            child: Text('Buscar',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PageView. Here's an example of how to implement one, please try it:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page view example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('Other content'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: PageView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _pageController,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Next'),
                        onPressed: nextPage,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Go to page 3'),
                        onPressed: () => goToPage(2),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Previous'),
                        onPressed: prevPage,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Next'),
                        onPressed: nextPage,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Previous'),
                        onPressed: prevPage,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Go to page 1'),
                        onPressed: () => goToPage(0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
              ],
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void nextPage() {
    _pageController.animateToPage(_pageController.page.toInt() + 1,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        curve: ElasticOutCurve()
    );
  }

  void prevPage() {
    _pageController.animateToPage(_pageController.page.toInt() - 1,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        curve: ElasticOutCurve()
    );
  }

  void goToPage(int pageNumber) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(pageNumber,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        curve: ElasticOutCurve()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The user can scroll the page with their fingers if desired. I don't want this to happen, I want to change the view only if the user touches the button, any solution?

Comment: and suppose I have 4 "next buttons", is there any way that each button redirects to a different page (but just change the view in this red container), yes? how? that is my problem.

Comment: I found a way to disable the scroll by doing. physics:new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), inside PageView. My last problem is how I redirect the view in every single button? for example I have 3 buttons in the main container, and I want that the button 1 redirect me to widget 1 (can be a container) and button 2 redirect to widget 2.. etc. I want to personalize my own view with every single button

Comment: I am going to update the answer with buttons that go directly to a specific page.

Comment: I have now put a function 2 buttons to go directly to a specific page. Check my update, and if this fixes your issue please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help it works pretty nice. I am still trying to figure out how works `_pageController.animateToPage(_pageController.page.toInt() + 1`